# Application protocol used by Autosys CA for triggering an UNIX script

Tags: autosys

We are trying to setup Autosys 11.3 client in Linux and trigger our UNIX scripts residing in the server.
Which one of the below application protocol is used by Autosys CA for triggering an UNIX script ?  or is it anything else apart from the below?
HTTP, HTTPS, SFTP, FTP, FTPS, SQLnet, RDP, SMTP, JDBC, ODBC

Answer (score 0):

Just use the command job type for this. There is no specific job type for unix or windows scripts.
Dave

Comment: Thanks David. Does the command job type falls under any of these:HTTP, HTTPS, SFTP, FTP, FTPS, SQLnet, RDP, SMTP, JDBC, ODBC? if no, what would be the protocol for for command job type. Need to update this info in our intake sheet. Thanks.

Comment: no, command or cmd is a standalone job type. If you are doing jil then the: job_type: CMD if you are doing it through the GUI (WCC) under quick edit -> Create -> right at the top below Box it says command. Under command put your script.